# Sending inline strings through SES API of Amazon

Tags: amazon-ses

I am trying to send barcode along with my html mail content through amazon.I am using SES service .

In mail img tag is added with src="cid:barcodeImage"

and ses code is

```
if (is_array($files)) {

        $count = count($files);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $attach .= "\n";
            $attach .= "--$this->boundary\n";
            $attach .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
            $attach .= "Content-ID: <$file[cid]>\n";
            $clean_filename = self::clean_filename($file["name"], self::MAX_ATTACHMENT_NAME_LEN);
            $attach .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=$clean_filename;\n";
            $attach .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$clean_filename;\n";
            $attach .= "\n";
            $attach .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file['string']), 76, "\n");
            $attach .= "\n--$this->boundary";
        }
        // close email
        $attach .= "--\n";
    }
```

but instead of coming as an embedded string its coming as an attachment in mail
Is it possible to send embedded images in amzon ses?

Comment: Why don't you write a pure html body email and call the image from an absolute url? You'll be able to lighten the email itself and if you add the image in a cdn, it will dowload faster.

Comment: Some mailers will not show external urls

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by providing the image source as base64encoded data. In python i am doing like this:

```py
    x = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(base64.b64encode(open('x.png', 'rb').read()).decode())
```

Hope this will fix your issue and let me know if any issues